# How do I invoke a function from a dynamic class from a module?

Tags: python

Normal way:

```
import ham
ham.eggs.my_func()
ham.sausage.my_func()
```

How I want it "Dynamic" way:

```
str = 'eggs'
ham.str.my_func()
str = 'sausage'
ham.str.my_funct()
```

Same thing, but ideally how I would use it in a loop:

```
for x in ['eggs', 'sausage']
    ham.x.my_func()
```

Basically, I want a string tell which class's my_func to invoke?

Comment: `ham.str.my_func()` doesn't actually work, you know...

Comment: No, I want to do that. That is why I'm asking the question. That is my intent.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear from how you wrote the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getattr(ham, x).my_func()
```

This gets the method/thing (Python is duck typed) from `ham` which was assigned as an attribute whose name was the contents of `x` (if `x` is `'foo'`, then it'll be `ham.foo`), then invokes `my_func` on that

If `ham` has no method with the right name, you'll get an exception.

Incidentally, your example of `ham.str.my_func()` should be `getattr(ham, str).my_func()`.

If you want to **really** do this the right way, you could use the `imp` method to only get members of a certain type, or use additional introspection.

Comment: what if I also want to make the my_func() as a string as well? that is to say...

    my_func = 'bread'
    ham.str.my_func()

Comment: Watch out with variables named `str`. You're hiding a built-in class.

Comment: @johnsmith: you do the same thing again, but this time with feeling: `getattr(getattr(ham, x), my_func)()` is equivalent to `ham.<contents of x>.<contents of my_func>.__call__()`.

Comment: @Borealid awesome! thanks =) when you said the correct way is to use imp? can you give an example, please? thanks for being very helpful

Comment: @johnsmith I actually meant to say `inspect` ( http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html ). It has loads of functions for introspecting. And using `getattr` is just fine if you handle the oops-it's-not-a-function or oops-it's-not-there cases.